# How to check for empty-string, null or white-spaces in handlebar?

Tags: handlebars.js, template-engine

I need to check for null values, empty-strings and strings with whitespaces only and substitute them with "No Content".

I tried this but it worked only for null and empty string not for whitespaces-only strings.

```html
{{#if value}}
    {{value}}
{{else}}
    <p>No Content</p>
{{/if}}
```

How to do it? Is helpers the only option?

Answer (score 3):

This is a useful Helper.

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('check', function(value, comparator) {
    return (value === comparator) ? 'No content' : value;
});
```

Tests template

```js
{{#check value ""}}
  {{this}}
{{/check}}

{{#check value null}}
  {{this}}
{{/check}}

{{#check value undefined}}
  {{this}}
{{/check}}
```

Comment: this is useful. how to implement else in this case? something like {{#check value ""}}
  {{this}} {{else "my custom value"}}
{{/check}}

Answer (score 1):

As you have alluded to in your question, a String with a non-zero length, even if it contains only space characters, is [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) in JavaScript. This is why a String of whitespace characters will match the `{{if value}}` case in your template and render the value instead of rendering the `{{else}}` case.

As yours is a special case where you want to treat Strings of only whitespace characters the same as empty, `null` and `undefined`, you will need to create a custom Handlebars Helper.

One way you could do the evaluation in your helper would be to use a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to remove all whitespace characters and then check the length of the result. The helper could look like:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifEmptyOrWhitespace', function (value, options) {
    if (!value) { return options.fn(this); }
    return value.replace(/\s*/g, '').length === 0
        ? options.fn(this)
        : options.inverse(this);
});
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/80g7zcwh/) for reference.